# Returning boolean if set is empty

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am struggling to find a more clean way of returning a boolean value if my set is empty at the end of my function

I take the intersection of two sets, and want to return `True` or `False` based on if the resulting set is empty.

```
def myfunc(a,b):
    c = a.intersection(b)
    #...return boolean here
```

My initial thought was to do

```
return c is not None
```

However, in my interpreter I can easily see that statement will return true if `c = set([])`

```
>>> c = set([])
>>> c is not None
True
```

I've also tried all of the following:

```
>>> c == None
False
>>> c == False
False
>>> c is None
False
```

Now I've read from the documentation that I can only use `and`, `or`, and `not` with empty sets to deduce a boolean value. So far, the only thing I can come up with is returning not not c

```
>>> not not c
False
>>> not c
True
```

I have a feeling there is a much more pythonic way to do this, by I am struggling to find it. I don't want to return the actual set to an if statement because I don't need the values, I just want to know if they intersect.

Comment: empty set is considered to be boolean False equivalent if you cast it so: `bool(set([]))`

Comment: by the way, seriously well worked out question, which is remarkable.

Comment: @JonasWielicki Thanks! Appreciate the answer - knew it was something along those lines.

Comment: This question is going to turn 5 years and nobody suggested using [`isdisjoint`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.isdisjoint). I'm completely shocked.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

```
def myfunc(a,b):
    c = a.intersection(b)
    return bool(c)
```

[`bool()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool) will do something similar to `not not`, but more ideomatic and clear.

Comment: I object, writing `bool(...)` when you're asking `is_empty` is obscure. I does not express the intent.

Comment: @tamas.kenez You have to admit, though, that it is clearer than ``not not`` ;). (FTR: I had already upvoted @gefeis answer, but I do not have influence on the thing OP accepted…)

Answer (score 151):

not as pythonic as the other answers, but mathematics:

```
return len(c) == 0
```

---

As some comments wondered about the impact `len(set)` could have on complexity. It is O(1) as shown in the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e005ead49b1ee2b1507ceea94e6f89c28ecf1f81/Objects/setobject.c#L538-L541) given it relies on a variable that tracks the usage of the set.

```
static Py_ssize_t
set_len(PyObject *so)
{
    return ((PySetObject *)so)->used;
}
```

Comment: I think this is actually better. It makes it clearer what your intent is.

Comment: Definitely a good suggestion - might make it more readable in the future will definitely consider it.

Comment: I'm afraid this will have to compute `len(c)` even if `c` is very large, which is unnecessary in order to check for emptiness.

Comment: @Glaedr I believe in cpython len for commonly used data structures (i.e. list, set) is O(1) (i.e. they store a variable on the datastructure representing the length)

Comment: ^ +1 @C.B. i did some tests on len(c) and it definitely is some variable representing len because there was negligible runtime difference when set size changed dramatic orders of magnitude.

Comment: @dster77 i profiled my code with both versions and it was significantly faster when comparing with `set()` (python 3.5.2 in windows)

Comment: Given the discussion around the complexity and the upvoted comment from @MicheleDePascalis I am adding the len(set) complexity into the answer to make it clear it is O(1) so it won't be a problem.

Comment: In Scott Meyers's "Effective STL", chapter 1, item 4: "Call empty() instead of checking size() against zero." The same applies not just to C++ STL, but to all programming languages, for obvious reasons (the compuation of the length is unnecessary). Therefore I gave this a downvote.

Comment: python does not have an "empty" for a set. that's the issue, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 34):

If you want to `return True` for an empty set, then I think it would be clearer to do:

```
return c == set()
```

i.e. "`c` is equal to an empty `set`".

(Or, for the other way around, `return c != set()`).

In my opinion, this is more explicit (though less idiomatic) than relying on Python's interpretation of an empty set as `False` in a boolean context.

Comment: Actually, relying on Python's interpretation is very acceptable practice. As long as its limitations kept in mind.

Answer (score 23):

If `c` is a set then you can check whether it's empty by doing: `return not c`.

If `c` is empty then `not c` will be `True`.

Otherwise, if `c` contains any elements `not c` will be `False`.

Answer (score 11):

When you say:

```
c is not None
```

You are actually checking if c and None reference the same object. That is what the "is" operator does. In python None is a special null value conventionally meaning you don't have a value available. Sorta like null in c or java. Since python internally only assigns one None value using the "is" operator to check if something is None (think null) works, and it has become the popular style. However this does not have to do with the truth value of the set c, it is checking that c actually is a set rather than a null value.

If you want to check if a set is empty in a conditional statement, it is cast as a boolean in context so you can just say:

```
c = set()
if c:
   print "it has stuff in it"
else:
   print "it is empty"
```

But if you want it converted to a boolean to be stored away you can simply say:

```
c = set()
c_has_stuff_in_it = bool(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"""
This function check if set is empty or not.
>>> c = set([])
>>> set_is_empty(c)
True

:param some_set: set to check if he empty or not.
:return True if empty, False otherwise.
"""
def set_is_empty(some_set):
    return some_set == set()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as clean as bool(c) but it was an excuse to use ternary.

```
def myfunc(a,b):
    return True if a.intersection(b) else False
```

Also using a bit of the same logic there is no need to assign to c unless you are using it for something else.

```
def myfunc(a,b):
    return bool(a.intersection(b))
```

Finally, I would assume you want a True / False value because you are going to perform some sort of boolean test with it. I would recommend skipping the overhead of a function call and definition by simply testing where you need it.

Instead of:

```
if (myfunc(a,b)):
    # Do something
```

Maybe this:

```
if a.intersection(b):
    # Do something
```